# Dual and reduced costs using SimplexSolver from ojAlgo

Tags: ojalgo, linear-optimization

I would like to solve a linear problem using the simplex from ojAlgo (version 51.4.0) and to be able to retrieve its dual variables as well as its reduced costs. I was expecting the method `getMultipliers()` from `Result` to return the dual variables but it is not the case in my example (see code below).

My questions are the following:

1. How to retrieve the dual variables?
2. How to retrieve the reduced costs?
3. What is the best way to force the usage of one solver (`SimplexSolver` in my case)?

For question 3, I have used `primModel.options.debug(SimplexSolver.class)` as `addPreferredSolver()` is deprecated. While working, I was wondering if there is a preferred way.

I would like to be able to retrieve those information outside of an ojAlgo fork (the classes `PrimalSimplex` and `DualSimplex` seem interesting here but they cannot be used, as they cannot be accessed from outside the package).

```java
/**
 * problem from https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15859-f11/www/notes/lecture05.pdf
 *
 * problem: maximize 2 * x1 + 3 *x2
 *      s.t.    4 * x1 + 8 * x2 <= 12
 *              2 * x1 +     x2 <= 3
 *              3 * x1 + 2 * x2 <= 4
 *              x1, x2 >= 0
 */
ExpressionsBasedModel primModel = new ExpressionsBasedModel(); // problem to solve
Variable x1 = primModel.addVariable("X1").lower(0).weight(2); // maximize 2 * x1
Variable x2 = primModel.addVariable("X2").lower(0).weight(3); //            ... + 3 * x2
Expression a1 = primModel.addExpression(); // constraints to respect
Expression a2 = primModel.addExpression();
Expression a3 = primModel.addExpression();
a1.set(x1, 4).set(x2, 8).upper(12); // 4 * x1 + 8 * x2 <= 12
a2.set(x1, 2).set(x2, 1).upper(3);  // 2 * x1 +     x2 <= 3
a3.set(x1, 3).set(x2, 2).upper(4);  // 3 * x1 + 2 * x2 <= 4

// force the use of simplex (question 3)
primModel.options.debug(SimplexSolver.class);
Optimisation.Result result = primModel.maximise();

// does not give the dual variables: no value present within the optional
Optional<Access1D<?>> multipliers = result.getMultipliers();

System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LinearSolver` does return the dual variables, but:

1. When the LP is generated from an `ExpressionsBasedModel` the reverse mapping, from LP-constraint to lower/upper limits on the variables and expressions of the model, is not implemented. So, the result returned by the `ExpressionsBasedModel` does not contain the dual variables. To get the dual variables you have to skip using `ExpressionsBasedModel` and instead us the builders in `LinearSolver` directly.
2. In the linear solver/builder code there is logic to handle if the duals are needed or not. Don't remember exactly how this works. I think that when you use the builders you always get the duals. You have to check.

If you want to control which solver the `ExpressionsBasedModel` will select you have to code an implementation of `ExpressionsBasedModel.Integration` and then register that using `ExpressionsBasedModel#addIntegration(Integration<?>)`. This functionality exists to be able to use 3:d party solvers like CPLEX, GUROBI, MOSEK and others.